# Sword deal damage only when swinging?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a simple 3D Sword swinging animation and a damage script. However, the enemy takes damage whenever it comes in contact with the sword... even when it is not swinging! How do I make it that the enemy takes damage only when the swinging animation takes place???

Comment: Along with your animation, you can enable and disable components on your object. One way to do this is directly adding a keyframe during the animation that enables during a short time as your sword is fully extended or when the animation starts, then at the end disabling it. Another is using an [animation event](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html). When this event is triggered, a function in code is called. Likewise, you can enable/disable the collider at these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I can’t see your script, so I will have to guess with what you have. I assume you detect input to swing the sword, so this should work if you know how to add the concept to your script. (This script is meant to be on the sword.)

```
bool swinging = false;

void Update(){
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
      swinging = true;
      //play animation
   }
   if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
      swinging = false;
      //stop animation
   }
}
void OnCollisonEnter(Collision col){
   var obj = col.GameObject;
   if (obj.Tag == “Enemy” && swinging){//change string to enemy tag
      obj.GetComponent<DamageScriptName>().DamageVariable -= 1;
   }
}
```

This should work if you change certain variables. The variables to change is the damaged script name in the on collision enter, the damage variable, and the tag. Also add something to play the animation in the update function where I put the comments.

This works by detecting if the player presses the mouse button, while it is down, it will set swinging to true. If you release from the button, it will set swinging to false. Then I use OnCollisionEnter() to see when the sword hits anything. If it does, then it will check if the tag is the one of the enemy, and if the sword is swinging. If those are true, then it gets into the script on the enemy, (make sure to change the variables I wrote.) and gets the health variable, and subtracts one from it. This is what the enemy script should look like if you used the exact code I put down:

```
public float DamageVariable;
float maxHealth = 5f;
public float health;

void Update(){
   health = maxHealth + DamageVariable;
   if (health =< 0){
      Death();
   }
}
void Death(){
   Debug.Log(“enemy dead”);
   Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

This detects of the enemy’s health is 0, and if it is, it will be destroyed. (Make sure this script is called “DamageScriptName”, and is on the enemy you attack.

Edit:
For this edit: change the script to this:

Add this one to the player.

```cs
bool swinging = false;

void Update(){
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
      swinging = true;
      //play animation
   }
   if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
      swinging = false;
      //stop animation
   }
}
```

Add this script to the sword.

```cs
public GameObject player; //drag player object in this slot.
bool swinging;

void Update(){
   swinging = player.GetComponent<replace>().swinging; //change ‘replace’ to the name of the script I wrote up there ^.
}
void OnCollisonEnter(Collision col){
   if (col.GameObject.Tag == “Enemy” && swinging){//change string to enemy tag
      col.GameObject.GetComponent<DamageScriptName>().DamageVariable -= 1;
   } //it’s hard for me to remember, but if you get any errors talking about assembly
//references or something like that with the namespace ‘GameObject’, change the
// capitol G to a lowercase, wherever it throws the error.
}
```

The changes I made was splitting the scripts in two, and using `GetComponent<>();` to access the variables in there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this after dinner

Comment: Hmmm, the thing is, the swinging animation script is in my player, not the sword.

Comment: Okay. I will edit it as soon as I can to fit your needs.